# Google Apps Marketplace - Adding scopes via Incremental authorisation

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-signin, service-accounts

We have an existing web app which uses Google's OAuth 2.0 APIs for Admin Directory, Drive, etc for administrative tasks like backup and audit.

Currently we let our customers install backup and audit independently as 'modules' and each have separate `client_id`s and separate OAuth scopes (i.e. Admin directory for one, Drive for another).

We want to bring our app to the Google Apps Marketplace, and take advantage of Google Sign In (OpenID Connect), use service accounts with domain-wide delegation of authority, but still let our customers only authorize scopes they want to use.

Can we add new scopes to Google Apps Marketplace apps when a user wants to enable a certain feature?

The best practise guidelines (1) indicate that we should request all scopes we might want up front via the Marketplace SDK scopes section but we want to only request the scopes our customers are going to actually use.

(1) https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices#1_complete_the_listing_review_request_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new scopes.  Your customer will still have to grant access though for the new scope/s from the ADMIN console.

Comment: So am I understanding correctly: the customer will need to go to the Google Apps Admin console to grant access to new scopes? Can we not just go through the OAuth 2.0 authorization flow again to add scopes as we can in a non-marketplace app?

Comment: Yes they need to go to the ADMIN console.  There is also no 'notification' if you like that they need to do this, you need to tell them to do it.

Comment: The thing that wasn't clear to me was that scopes work quite differently via the marketplace vs normal OAuth 2.0 authorization. For anyone with a similar question, the scopes you are requesting for the marketplace are set in the marketplace SDK configuration on the developer console. To get additional scopes customers need to manually add more scopes via the admin console (Security -> Show More -> Advanced settings -> Manage API client access). The idea is that you use marketplace scopes with a service account to get domain-wide access.