# Publish Apps Scripts Web App on the Google Apps Market Place

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Google Apps Scripts web app and I would like to publish it on the Google Apps Market Place. I followed this instruction (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/domain-wide-web-app) to properly setup the Apps Market Place SDK but I have some troubles.

To test installation flow I use the button in the setup page of the API, so :
My issue is if a user install the app as I allow personal install
The user validate rights and after he is redirected to the application. There I have an issue because the apps script web app request a "Offline access" in a new pop up.

=> I don't know how to add this scope because I don't find any scope for this need to add in the market place SDK setup. 
What I found on stackoverflow is I probably have this message because on scope request by apps script web app there is the approval_prompt parameter set to force.

My question is how to avoid that and allow user to connect to app after validating scope on the apps market place ?

Thank you,
Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [**List of Best Practices**](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices)

> Before you publish your Google App Marketplace application, please review the following list of best practices. Adhering to these best practices will help your application make it through the Google Apps Marketplace review process smoothly without you needing to make additional changes.

This document explain:

> 3: Define your scopes properly
>
> All OAuth2.0 scopes must be defined in the Google Developer's Console, in the Scopes section of the Google Apps Marketplace SDK. This is essential in order to achieve **one-click or zero-click SSO**, as described in the following section.

According to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727674/google-apps-marketplace-adding-scopes-via-incremental-authorisation), in the Admin Conso

Comment: Thank you for yçur message but my point is a bit more specific because with apps script I don't have the hand on everything. The point raised is also link to the parameterapproval_prompt and I can't change that by myself it is define for app script.

Comment: List of Best Practices : https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices does not exist